# Заглушка во время длительной операции

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Допустим, в WinForms приложении есть метод, который долго выполняется=> на форме создается эффект зависания, но я не хочу давать пользователю возможность ничего делать, пока не завершится операция.

Как я могу предупредить его об этом? Я попробовал создать форму-заглушку с сообщением и отобразить ее через Show() и потом вызвать этот метод, но на этой форме даже Label нормально не отображается...

В отдельный поток чтоль форму-заглушку кидать?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5):

Да, отображение "заглушек" в отдельном потоке - популярная практика.

Форму лучше создавать в том потоке, в котором она будет показываться.

Возможна проблема с закрытием формы - надо ведь сначала получить закрываемый объект из другого потока. Сложность тут в том, что "долгая" операция может выполниться быстрее чем форма будет создана...

Рекомендую синхронизацию через механизм токенов отмены, потому что они берут на себя большинство проблем синхронизации:

```
static void RunLongOperationForm(object obj) {
  var token = (CancellationToken)obj;

  Thread.Sleep(100);
  if (token.IsCancellationRequested) return;

  var form = new LongOperationForm();
  form.Shown += (o, e) => token.Register(form.Close, useSynchronizationContext: true);
  Application.Run(form);
}

// Показ формы:
formShowCTS = new CancellationTokenSource();
new Thread(RunLongOperationForm).Start(formShowCTS.Token);

// Отмена показа формы:
formShowCTS.Cancel();
formShowCTS.Dispose();
```

Что здесь делается. Во-первых, я откладываю показ заглушки на 100 миллисекунд, чтобы она не показывалась в том случае, когда "долгая" операция оказалась быстрой.

Во-вторых, для того, чтобы определить момент закрытия формы, я использую `token.Register`. Этот метод запоминает некоторый делегат (в данном случае - `form.Close`) и вызывает его при получении сигнала отмены.

Но закрыть можно только открытую форму - поэтому я подписываюсь на событие показа формы, чтобы вызвать там `token.Register`.

Также я использую `useSynchronizationContext: true`, чтобы форма закрывалась в потоке этой самой формы (без этого параметра метод `form.Close()` будет вызван в том потоке, в котором вызвали `formShowCTS.Cancel()` - а это ошибка).

---

Но лучше все-таки в отдельный поток вынести долгую операцию :)

Comment: А как это выглядит в коде? Форма должна быть создана в отдельном потоке и там же вызван метод Show или нужно сначала создать форму, а потом вызвать Show в отдельном потоке?

Comment: @iluxa1810 привел код

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте сделать на первой же форме label с предупреждением. Запишите в него предупреждение перед тем как метод начнёт работу. И после окончания действия метода скройте label.